# No hosts found: Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

when I run my python code it is  asking for host.

> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

I have the following code:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm

env.hosts = [ 'ipaddress' ]

def remoteRun():
    print "ENV %s" %(env.hosts)
    out = run('uname -r')
    print "Output %s"%(out)

remoteRun();
```

I even tried running fab with -H option and I am getting the same message. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 any help is appreciated. Btw I am a newbie in Python.

Comment: @arie below has provided correct answer. Last remoteRun() in the script needs to be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what `remoteRun();` is supposed to do in your example.

Is it part of your fabfile or is this your terminal command to invoke the script?

The correct way would be a command like this in your shell:

`fab remoteRun`

Generally it's better to specify the concrete hosts your command is supposed to run on like this:

```
def localhost():
    env.hosts = [ '127.0.0.1']

def remoteRun():
    print "ENV %s" %(env.hosts)
    out = run('uname -r')
    print "Output %s"%(out)
```

You can run it like this from a terminal (assuming you are in the directory that contains your fabfile):

```
fab localhost remoteRun
```

As an alternative you could specify the host with the -H parameter:

```
fab -H 127.0.0.1 remoteRun
```

If you have a list of hosts you want to invoke the command for, do it like this:
http://readthedocs.org/docs/fabric/latest/usage/execution.html

Adjusted to your example:

```
env.hosts = [ 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

def remoteRun():
    print "ENV %s" %(env.hosts)
    out = run('uname -r')
    print "Output %s"%(out)
```

And called via: `fab remoteRun`

This way the `remoteRun` is performed on all hosts in `env.hosts`.

Answer (score 16):

In order to get hosts to work in a script outside of the fab command-line tool and fabfile.py, [you'll have to use execute()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute):

```py
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.tasks import execute

def mytask():
    run('uname -a')

results = execute(mytask)
```

Comment: Took me quite a while to find this I'm surprised it's not more upvoted, I figured more people would be wanting to call a fabric command from another python script.

Answer (score 15):

If it's only one host, you can use `env.host_string = 'somehost or ipaddress'`.

You also don’t need the `;` at the end of your `remoteRun`.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
from fabric.api import env, run

env.host_string = 'ipaddress'

def remoteRun():
    print "ENV %s" %(env.hosts)
    out = run('uname -r')
    print "Output %s"%(out)

remoteRun()
```

Comment: Why isn't Fabric smart and just work with a env.hosts of length 1?

Answer (score 5):

@Nerdatastic is right, for simple:  don't use  env.hosts, use env.host_string instead. e.g.

```
def setup_db_server
  env.host_string = 'db01.yoursite.com'   # or the ip address
  run("mysqladmin ...")
end
```

and running `$ fab setup_db_server`  will execute the script on the target server.

Answer (score 4):

Nerdatastic is right, you need to specify the env.host_string varaible for fabric to know what host string to use. I came across this problem trying to use a subclass of Task and call the run() method. It seemed to ignore env.hosts except when using execute from fabric.tasks in version 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue.

I think this is a bug. Because all work before today.
I store my env in .fabricrc.

Now i have same message as yours. Don't know why.